# Java Applet Conversion

Tags: java, applet

i made a Binary Calculator in Java GUI. IT contains:constructos,actionlistener,main funcion and so on. Now i want it to be also an applet. Application and applet in the same time. Unfortunately i cant make it happen.

```
/* <applet code = "Calculator" width = 320 height = 200> </applet> */

public class Calculator extends Applet implements ActionListener {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Calculator();
            }
        });
    }

    Applet applet = this;

    public void init() {
        new Calculator();
    }

}
```

So I would be grateful if somebody could present the easiest way to transform it to the applet.Thank u in advance.

Comment: 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) Why AWT rather than Swing?  See my answer on [Swing extras over AWT](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6255978/418556) for many good reasons to abandon using AWT components.

Answer (score 0):

change it to the following:

```
public class Calculator extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    Calculator() {

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Calculator calc = new Calculator();
        calc.setSize(320, 200);
        calc.setVisible(true);
        calc.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```